# magento set store view by store id

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, multistore, store-view

Is it possible to set magento store view with help of store id and store code programmatically?

```
$store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($store_id); 
$code  = $store->getCode();
```

With the help of above code I can able to get store code. Now how to set store view with the help of id and code? I tried searching for solution but couldn't able to find it.

Comment: Depending of what you exactly want to achieve, there are better methods than editing the index.php which quite is part of the magento core. So, what is the goal?

Comment: Actually I have few users(vendors) who have created stores in magento admin panel. So, when they login into admin panel, I have to write an observer event(admin_session_user_login_success) to find which user has logged in so that I can set his store automatically.

Comment: So what you want to do is set the select box in the upper left automatically? You are NOT talking about frontend stores?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm talking about backend. Not frontend. I want to set the select box automatically when user enters admin panel

Answer (score 1):

To implement this functionality I would have a look on how the select works.

The select calls a JS function `switchStore` which is defined here: `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/dashboard/store/switcher.phtml:56`

This function calls a url: `\Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Store_Switcher::getSwitchUrl`

and here I'm stuck. I have no idea where this url parameter is processed. So you have two options:

1. reveal this secret or
2. hook into `admin_session_user_login_success` after the login, redirect the user to the right store, which means get the url and set the `store` parameter.

It might be needed to `die()` in your controller which is really bad habit, this is because of the header() after the event:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php:104
Mage::dispatchEvent('admin_session_user_login_success', array('user' => $user));
header('Location: ' . $requestUri);
```

Comment: Yes, even I have been looking into the core folder to see how this works and I was stuck too. As you said, passing the store parameter would solve my problem. Vendor user have access only to catalog > manage product link ( I have restricted access in users permission settings). Is it possible to get catalog > manage product link in my observer? If so how to do it? Can you guide?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it. for that edit index.php file, add the following

```
$store_id = 'your_store_id_here';
$mageRunCode = 'store view code';
$mageRunType = 'store';

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store_id);
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

Answer (score 0):

For future refernce and anyone wondering how to implement such a thing. this is how I did something similar where I had to make every admin see only items (products, categories... etc) and store filters that are assigned to him/her.

**First step:**
Modified the table admin_user adding a column to specify the website for that admin.

**Step two**
Identifying where the changes need to be made, and apparently, there are multiple store switchers and each is used for a different page, categories has one, and products has another.

**Step three**
Now I override/change the code in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Store/Switcher.php`
in the function `getWebsiteCollection` to be something like this:

```
public function getWebsiteCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('core/website')->getResourceCollection();
    $websiteIds = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getWebsiteIds();
    $storeIdInRequest    = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store');
    if (!is_null($websiteIds)) {
            $website = explode(",",$websiteIds);
            $website = Mage::app()->getWebsite($website[0]);
            if($storeId==0){
                    $storIdYouWantToRedirectTo = // get The store Id you want to redirect to
                    $response = Mage::app()->getResponse();
                    $response->setRedirect($this->getSwitchUrl()."store/".$storIdYouWantToRedirectTo);
            }
        $collection->addIdFilter($websiteIds);
    }
    return $collection->load();
}
```

The previous code does two things:

1. It Filters the Switcher's websites depending on the admin's websites
2. If the current store is not specified in the request, it redirects to the same page but with a `store` parameter set to the needed value

Hope this helps... I'm still testing this, so I don't really know if this has any side effects, and I'm implementing on a more pages than you need, so if I find any tricks or gotcha's in this I will be updating this answer.